# WCF Service : config address

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, service, wcfserviceclient

In my WCF Service `App.config` I have :

```
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceWcfBehavior" name="MyService">
    <clear />
    <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:9999/MyService" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="MyServiceTcpBinding" name="MyServiceWcfTcpEndpoint" contract="MyService.Contracts.Interfaces.IMy" />
  </service>
</services>
```

And in my test-client `App.config` I have :

```
<client>
  <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:9999/MyService" behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceEndpointBehavior" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="MyServiceCustomTcpBinding" contract="MyService.Contracts.Interfaces.IMy" name="MyServiceWcfTcpEndpoint" />
</client>
```

Then I instantiate my `ServiceHost` like this :

```
var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService),new Uri(net.tcp://localhost:9999/MyService));
host.Open();
```

But on running my service and then testing with my client ( calling channel endpoint defined in my service ) I get runtime exception :

> System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1 was unhandled
>   Action=http://schemas.microsoft.com/net/2005/12/windowscommunicationfoundation/dispatcher/fault
>         HResult=-2146233087
>         Message=The method or operation is not implemented.
>         Source=mscorlib
>         StackTrace:
>           Server stack trace: 
>              at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message
>   reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version,
>   FaultConverter faultConverter)
>              at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime
>   operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
>              at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
>              at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
>              at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)
>           Exception rethrown at [0]: 
>              at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
>              at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)

Comment: Is the method you're trying to call via the test client implemented in the service?

Answer (score 0):

When using Port sharing, you need to pass a `NetTcpBinding` with `PortSharingEnabled` set to `true` to the constructor:

```
portsharingBinding = new NetTcpBinding();
portsharingBinding.PortSharingEnabled = true;

var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService), portsharingBinding, new Uri("net.tcp://localhost:9999/MyService"));
host.Open();
```

Also, your have you made sure that your service implements an interface with the a `ServiceContract`

```
[ServiceContract]
interface IMyService 
{
    //Define the contract operations.  
}

class MyService : IMyService 
{  
    //Implement the IMyService operations. 
}
```

Also make sure the contract in your config  `MyService.Contracts.Interfaces.IMy` matches that interface  exactly. This is case sensitive.

Comment: sorry to be dense but how am i using port sharing ?  also the overload you provide for ServiceHost doesn't seem to exist.  all i have is an overload with URI as the 2nd arg

Comment: What version of .net are you using? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-configure-a-wcf-service-to-use-port-sharing